# Can't connect to the mapped drive in the server sometimes

Tags: windows, network-shares

I'm using windows 2012 server and the client is windows xp. There is no user in the server who is in the client, so I used the user in the server who has the authority over the server with password managed in scheduled task so that it could run every time client logs in. The server and client is connected in LAN network to the work group.
The problem is when the client logs in the scheduled task run the connection task and fails by showing the following error..

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
>   using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
>   previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

The screen shot of the error is[image]

This above problem occurs some times not always. Please tell me what is the problem and is there any other way to connect to the drives in the server?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that in your login script (or connection task) could contain  something like next CLI command `net use` or equivalent:

```
NET USE F: \\pc2\F /PERSISTENT:YES
```

You should either test whether connection is established already as follows:

```
if not exist F:\ NET USE F: \\pc2\F /PERSISTENT:YES
```

or disconnect mapping from the share before remapping it as follows:

```
NET USE F: /DELETE
NET USE F: \\pc2\F /PERSISTENT:YES
```

or even disconnect from the share and close all resources (undocumented `/Y` switch):

```
NET USE F: /DELETE /Y
NET USE F: \\pc2\F /PERSISTENT:YES
```

**Resource**: `NET USE /?` or [Map a drive letter to a remote server/share](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html).